# Kotlin combine more than 2 flows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

I'm looking to combine 4 StateFlow values and make 1 StateFlow from these. I know already of the combine function like this:

```
val buttonEnabled = cameraPermission.combine(micPermission) {
    //some logic
}
```

How could this be done with 4 flows? when I attempt the below, I get the error there is too many arguments, but the combine function docs do say you are able to add up to 5 flows?

```
val buttonEnabled = cameraPermission.combine(micPermission, locationPermission, contactsPermission) {

}
```

Comment: Use the top level `combine` function instead of the extension function and put all four of the flows in the parentheses.

Comment: This does solve the initial error but now i'm faced with this one: "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match".

Comment: @alfietap did you specify as many parameters in the lambda as you have flows in `combine`'s arguments?

Comment: nope there's my issue, all working now!

Comment: could you please explain how it is now working?

Comment: @Veit I didn't declare the parameters in the lambda braces

Answer (score 47, accepted):

"but the combine function docs do say you are able to add up to 5 flows?"

Yes syntax :

`combine(flow1, flow2, flow3, flow4) {t1, t2, t3, t4 -> resultMapper}.stateIn(scope)`

If you require more than 5 combined, then it is very simple to create your own functions example for 6 :

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    flow6: Flow<T6>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) -> R
): Flow<R> = combine(
    combine(flow, flow2, flow3, ::Triple),
    combine(flow4, flow5, flow6, ::Triple)
) { t1, t2 ->
    transform(
        t1.first,
        t1.second,
        t1.third,
        t2.first,
        t2.second,
        t2.third
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use combine() function from kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Zip.kt

eg.

combine(flow1, flow2, flow3) {f1,f2,f3->
// do something
}

Answer (score 0):

if you need to combine multiple same type flow regardless of length,

you can use this method to create

```kotlin
class Util {
    companion object {
        fun <T> getMultipleCombinedFlow(vararg flow: Flow<T>, transform: (T, T) -> T): Flow<T> {
            return combineMultiple(flow, 0, null, transform)
        }

        private fun <T> combineMultiple(
            array: Array<out Flow<T>>,
            index: Int = 0,
            combined: Flow<T>? = null,
            transform: (T, T) -> T
        ): Flow<T> {
            if (array.size == 1) {
                return array[0]
            }
            if (index >= array.size)
                return combined!!

            if (combined == null) {
                val result = array[index].combine(array[index + 1], transform)
                return combineMultiple(array, index + 2, result, transform)
            }

            val result = combined.combine(array[index], transform)
            return combineMultiple(array, index + 1, result, transform)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Feb 2024**
These are the most direct approaches :

| operator | description |
| --- | --- |
| `combine` | This operator takes multiple Flows and a transformation function as arguments. The transformation function receives the latest values from each flow and combines them into a single value emitted by the resulting flow. [Document](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) |
| `zip` | Similar to combine, but only emits when all input flows have emitted a value. Useful when you need to react to events happening simultaneously across multiple flows. [Document](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html) |

`combine` operator **example** :

```
val flow1 = flow { ... }
val flow2 = flow { ... }

val combinedFlow = combine(flow1, flow2) { value1, value2 ->
    // combine values here
    Pair(value1, value2) 
}

scope.launch {
    combined.collect{
        Log.e("TAG: ","${it.first} , ${it.second}")
    }
}
```

`zip` operator **example** :

```
val flow1 = flow { ... }
val flow2 = flow { ... }
val flow3 = flow { ... }

val zippedFlow = flow1.zip(flow2, flow3) { value1, value2, value3 ->
    // combine values here
    Triple(value1, value2, value3)
}

scope.launch {
    zippedFlow.collect { (value1, value2, value3) ->
        // Use the zipped values
        Log.e("TAG: ","${it.first} , ${it.second} , ${it.third}")
    }
}
```